# My car is at the garage vs my car is in the garage

Tags: grammaticality

(My car is at the garage.It is being repaired,somebody is repairing it ) I think it should be in instead of at because my car is present in the building/shed and it is not out present of building/shed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between the alternative forms is chiefly idiomatic. English speakers would **always prefer** “at the garage” to refer to the car being repaired at a workshop and would **generally prefer** “in the garage” to refer to your car being housed at your own premises.

Comment: This is not right. in the garage can two things : repair or where the car is (not on the street, parked in a garage). And it is not true that English speakers prefer one over the other.

Comment: This analysis is incorrect. It makes no difference at all if you think of *garage* as referring to a mechanic's shop or a part of a house

Comment: Wow, I’m surprised by these comments. You only have to think of a suitable context to realise “at the garage” does not naturally refer to a car housed in the home garage. For example: talking to my 20yo daughter about her car when we arrive at our shared home and notice no car on the street, I say, “where’s your car?” She will say, “IN the garage” (never “AT the garage”) to refer to the fact that it’s parked inside our nearby shed.

Answer (score 1):

- My car is at the garage. [yes, **being repaired**]
- My car is in the garage. [**also being repaired**]

but *in the garage* can also mean: it is in the garage and not on the street/outside.

[outside something]

Comment: @ManishkumarKumar Please, please do  not repeat the question. [why do we use, not why will be use. I have answered the question.

Comment: @ManishkumarKumar, you car may be _in_ the garage (building), but also _at_ the garage (business which engages in automobile maintenance and repair).

Comment: @ManishkumarKumar Because both ***at*** *the garage* and ***inside*** *the garage* refer to the same location of the car. It's just that there is a subtle difference between the two.